# register to rails (devise) backend with iOS Client

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

i am trying to register from an iOS App to a rails backend.

```
rake routes
```

tells me:

```
user_registration     POST   /users(.:format)         devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format) devise/registrations#new
```

So on the iOS Side i am trying this:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                             @"email": username,
                             @"password": password,
                             @"password_confirmation": passwordConfirmation
                             };

[[ADCAPIClient sharedClient] postPath:@"users"
                          parameters:parameters
                             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
```

I am getting an Unknown Format exception:

```
Started POST "/users" for 192.168.178.21 at 2013-11-02 18:53:08 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
Parameters:
{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"abc@def.de",
"registration"=>{"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>
"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"abc@def.de"}}

Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 6ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
```

If i connect through the devise generated view in the browser it works and the request it sends looks like this:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-03 10:58:54 +0100
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxx", "user"=>{"email"=>"abc@def.de", "password"=>
[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
...
```

I am doing the client backend communication for the first time, so i cannot figure out how the right request would look like?! I have searched stackoverflow, but the answers are pretty unsatisfying.
Can somebody help or provide me a link to a good explanation or tutorial?
Thanks in advance!